# ASSEMBLY Offset to C++ Code question

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assembly

I've been trying to convert this code to C++ without any inlining and I cannot figure it out..

Say you got this line

```
sub     edx, (offset loc_42C1F5+5)
```

My hex-rays gives me

```
edx -= (uint)((char*)loc_42C1F5 + 5))
```

But how would it really look like without the `loc_42C1F5`.

I would think it would be

```
edx -= 0x42C1FA;
```

But is that correct? (can't really step this code in any assembler-level debugger.. as it's damaged well protected)

loc_42C1F5 is a label actually..

```
seg000:0042C1F5 loc_42C1F5:                             ; DATA XREF: sub_4464A0+2B5o
seg000:0042C1F5                 mov     edx, [esi+4D98h]
seg000:0042C1FB                 lea     ebx, [esi+4D78h]
seg000:0042C201                 xor     eax, eax
seg000:0042C203                 xor     ecx, ecx
seg000:0042C205                 mov     [ebx], eax
```

Comment: I retract my answer since I clearly misinterpreted the brackets and the name offset.

Comment: it's cool now we both know.. I got lucky that tracking registers from very far ahead all on notepad and a calculator helped me out :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loc_42C1F5` is a symbol. Given the information you've provided, I cannot say what its offset is. It may be 0x42C1F5 or it may be something else entirely.

If it is 0x42C1F5, then your translation should be correct.

Comment: updated my post.. loc_42C1F5 is actually a label. `seg000:0042C1F5 loc_42C1F5:                             ; DATA XREF: sub_4464A0+2B5o`     ahhh thanks this really helped me out alot. I got that number from doing the subtraction.. and looking at registers what luck it's correct :P

Comment: I meant "symbol" in the general sense, which would include labels. So, in that case, I agree it would be equal to `edx -= 0x42C1FA;`.

Comment: thanks, everything works great.. reverse engineering is pretty fun.

Answer (score 0):

IDA has incorrectly identified 0x42C1FA as an offset, and Hex-Rays used that interpretation. Just convert it to plain number (press O) and all will be well. That's why it's called **Interactive** Disassembler :)

Comment: Wow thanks for the trick key: O i'll definitely have to remember that one. IDA makes alot of mistakes too! it makes some sections into dword's when it should be code.. but it's so easy just right click undefine and click create function haha.. Yup IDA is the only disassembler that could take over the decompiling / code porting to different languages etc.. field in the future..